# Packages for drawing 'fusion' diagrams in physics

Tags: tikz-pgf, packages

Using TikZ package, I want to draw the following kinds of diagrams:

[image]

The above image is obtained from a physics paper *Physical Review B 75, 045317 (2007)*. Since such  diagrams are common in physics, I suspect that there is some package that makes drawing such diagrams easier. Could you suggest such package?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure what a general diagram like this might look like, but this particular diagram can be drawn with standard `tikz` commands. You can adjust `xscale` and `yscale` if you wish.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\cdots
\begin{tikzpicture}[xscale=.8, yscale=.5, nodes={execute at begin node=$, execute at end node=$}]
\draw (-3,0)node[above]{I}--(3,0)node[above]{I};
\draw (-2,0)--(-2,1)node[above]{2j\!-\!1};
\draw (-1,0)--(-1,1)node[above]{2j};
\draw (1,0)--(1,1)node[above]{(2j)'};
\draw (2,0)--(2,1)node[above]{\quad(2j\!-\!1)'};
\node[above] at (0,0){c};
\end{tikzpicture}
\cdots.
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```